# Why does $R^{1}\pi_{S*}\mathcal{F}(r)$ vanish for large-enough $r$ if $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

Let $S$ be a Noetherian scheme and $\pi_{S}:\mathbb{P}^{n}_{S}=\mathbb{P}^{n}_{\mathbb{Z}}\times S$ be the usual projection. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf over $\mathbb{P}^{n}_{S}$. Since the category of coherent sheaves has enough projectives, one can form the right-derived functor $R\pi_{S*}\mathcal{F}$. Nitsure (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504590, p.14) makes the claim that for large-enough $r$, the first right-derived $R^{1}\pi_{S*}\mathcal{F}(r)$ vanishes.

Why is that so? Is this somehow analogous to Serre's theorem that $H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F}(r))$ vanishes for large-enough $r$ and $i\geq 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument about the right derived functor is unfortunately incorrect. Projective schemes of positive dimension [don't have enough projectives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319382/); the correct justification for the existence of the right derived functor is that there are enough *injectives*, see for instance Hartshorne section III.8.

Anyways, back to the issue at hand. The key fact here is the following:

> **Proposition** (Hartshorne III.8.5): Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme and let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of $X$ to an affine scheme $Y=\operatorname{Spec} A$. Then for any quasi-coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, we have $$R^if_*\mathcal{F}\cong H^i(X,\mathcal{F})^\sim.$$

With this in hand, we see that your conjecture is entirely correct. Cover $S$ with finitely many noetherian affine open subschemes $\operatorname{Spec} R_j$ and apply Serre's result to the induced maps $X\times_S \operatorname{Spec} R_j\to \operatorname{Spec} R_j$. Since there are finitely many $\operatorname{Spec} R_j$, we can pick some $r\gg 0$ so that $H^i(X\times_S \operatorname{Spec} R_j,\mathcal{F}|_\cdots(r))$ vanishes for all $j$. Since derived pushforward commutes with restriction on the target, we find that $R^if_*\mathcal{F}(r)=0$.

Comment: I see. But as if the category of coherent sheaves has not enough projectives and the $\mathcal{O}_{X}^{n}$ are not projective, why does Nitsure calculate the right-derived functor using free resolutions?

Comment: Where does this happen in the paper? What's probably happening is that one can compute derived functors from any acyclic resolution, so if the functor being computed can be calculated locally and patched together and satisfies the same sort of proposition as written in the post, it suffices for the resolution to be locally free in order to get the results one is after.

Comment: that's exactly what he's doing. Thanks. Sometimes even a genius like me (*sarcasm*) fails to see the wood for all the trees.