Splitting of Euler sequence
I am very new to algebraic geometry. When reading sheaf of differentials, I get confused about the following.
We know the euler exact sequence of $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ be
$$0\to \Omega_{X/k} \to \mathcal{O}(-1)^{n+1}\to \mathcal{O}_X \to 0.$$
Now $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module hence projective why is this Euler sequence does not split?
Thanks in advance.

The structure sheaf is not a projective object. The sequence is not-split because hint: compare global sections if there was a splitting.

@CraniumClamp by comparing global section I understand that the sequence will not split. But the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ is free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, then why it is not projective?

It is locally projective, and the sequence splits locally, but not globally.

Your question is related to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319382/hartshorne-exercise-iii-6-2-b-mathfrakqcox-need-not-have-enough-proje
